# Password Manager Pro backend database MS SQL vs PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, password-management

I'm looking to manage users passwords through the programme `Password Manager Pro`. Reading the documentation it explains that you can use ether your own `MS SQL` database or use their default `PostgreSQL` database.

Which of these would be better from a security point of view?

Comment: My opinion is to always favor open-source software, PostgreSQL in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The "most secure" one will be the DBMS that you and your staff know how to properly operate, maintain, and secure. So, it depends on your skillset.